# default image not showing

Tags: php, html

i have these codes

```
 <?php $defimg= "https://ind.proz.com/zf/images/default_user_512px.png";?>

 <?php $image_src = isset($League["name"]) ? $League["name"] : $defimg; ?>
```

HTML

```
 <img  src="/theme/Design/img/leagues-back/<?= $image_src; ?>.jpg" />
```

and my problem is the default image **$defimg** just not showing , its just showing the browser's default image ,

i just want to show a default image if **$image_src** has no image name match with
**$League["name"]**

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized I misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: your default image is an absolute path which you are putting in the middle of a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your default image is an absolute path and when it is used you end up with this as a URL:

```
/theme/Design/img/leagues-back/https://ind.proz.com/zf/images/default_user_512px.png.jpg
```

You can check the HTML source code in your web browser to see if this is the case. This might work resolve that issue:

```
<?php $defimg= "https://ind.proz.com/zf/images/default_user_512px.png";?>

<?php $image_src = isset($League["name"]) ? "/theme/Design/img/leagues-back/" . $League["name"] . ".jpg" : $defimg; ?>
```

And the link itself:

```
<img  src="<?= $image_src; ?>" />
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ,but that gave me this....





Error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: Typo. Was missing a quote so I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

since you are using php: You might wanna try this:

```
<?php $image_show = "/img_folder/image.png"; ?>
<?php echo "<img src='$image_show' height=51 width=50 style='border-radius: 5px;'>"; ?>
```

You may resize by changing height and width. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: what should be so different from what they're using now?

Comment: image is not showing in his code right? that is the main problem, so I am giving a code that works, image shows.....

Answer (score -1):

Do not mix php short tag "<=?" sintax with php common tag. Try to use always the php common tag because if you don't have the shortag option turned on in php.ini file it will never work and it will throw unknow errors.

Replace this line:

```
 <img  src="<?= $image_src; ?>" />
```

for this other one:

`<img  src="<?php $image_src; ?>" />`

Comment: `<?=` is shorthand syntax for `<?php echo` and has been around for a while. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Yeah @FunkFortyNiner on recent versions of course!  If you are working with an old lamp or xampp or even wamp version you will have this trouble i posted it. It happened to me before, something so dumb like this could perfectly break down a good clean code and a lot of people wouldn't notice it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but  shorthand syntax  is just works fine to showing an image , when there is a match image there i have no problem , i just want to show a  default when there is no match